# How to update value of column string in another DB while delete another

Tags: mysql, database, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Similar question to my question before but this one is little different. So I've got the following done which makes it delete my category bin;

CONTROLLER

```
def destroy
    @bin = Bin.find(params[:id])
    @bin.destroy
    redirect_to :dashboard_main
end
```

Each BIN also :has_many Savedtweets. The above, deletes the bin and even though in the model i can do :dependent => :destroy, how do I delete the Savedtweets when the BIN is deleted, but at the same time update another column named Newtweets and change the Status column value from "saved" to "new". I've tried doing this but got no idea about it and it works;

```
def destroy
    @bin = Bin.find(params[:id])
    @newtweet = Newtweet.find_by_tweet_id(@bins.savedtweet.tweet_id).update_all$
    @bin.destroy
    redirect_to :dashboard_main
end
```

It's ugly, but still doesn't work. The table Savedtweets and Newtweets use "tweet_id" and the id is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I read the question correctly, you want to update the `status` field of the `Newtweet` records that have the same `tweet_id` values as the `Savedtweet` records associated with the `@bin`.

One way to do that would be the following:

```
@bin = Bin.find(params[:id])
Newtweet.where(:tweet_id => @bin.savedtweets.pluck(:tweet_id)).update_all(:status => 'new')
```

If this is something that should happen any time a `Bin` is destroyed, you'll want to put it in a `before_destroy` callback, rather than the controller.

Comment: I did put the before_destroy in my bin model, however it didn't fire... if I put your solution in, it works ... your a genius.. but then why isn't my before_destory work.

Comment: @user2419316 Sorry, not sure why your callback isn't working - I use them all over the place. Perhaps that should be a new question?

Comment: True, true.. I'll post the question with my structure, thanks again sir!